# C# use moq to throw exception from async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, moq

I am using the Moq library as a mocking framework together with nunit. I am having trouble to figure out how to setup my mock object to throw an exception from an async method that returns a Task.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 9):

Async methods don't normally throw exceptions directly - they return tasks which end up being faulted. The simplest way to create such a task is to use [`Task.FromException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception).

You haven't given many details in your question, but I suspect if you just make your mock return the result of `Task.FromException` with the exception you want, that will simulate the error appropriately. The only downside is that the task will *immediately* be faulted, which will only test the "fast path" of anything awaiting it - it won't test the situation where the exception is only thrown later. To do that, you could write your own little async helper method:

```
// Create a non-generic one if you want, too
private static async Task<T> DelayFaultedTask(Exception e)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    throw e;
}
```

Then call that to obtain a "delay-faulted" task to return from your mock.

Comment: Since `Task.FromException` was introduced in 4.6, could you update your answer to include how to do this in earlier frameworks (4.5.2)?  Would this require a static helper method, `Task.Run(() => throw new Exception()")`, or is there a better way?

Comment: @PhilipPittle: Well I'd probably just write a method exactly the same as `DelayFaultedTask` but without the `await Task.Yield()` part...

Comment: This worked for me when I wanted to moq an async method to prove the consuming code was correctly dealing with the .IsFaulted property of the response from that method